# Filter not working in Angular JS ng-grid

Tags: angularjs

I'm struggling with implementing filtering on a button click in `angular js`.

I have a input search text box, search button and a grid as below

```
  <div ng-controller="NewsController">        
        Search
        <input type="text" 
               ng-model="searchtext">
        <button class="fa fa-search" 
                type="submit" 
                ng-click="searchNewsOrGuidelines();">
        </button> 
       <zoom-ui-grid options="NewsGridOptions" 
                     class="gridStyle">
       </zoom-ui-grid>   
  </div>
```

Filter implementation is as below, which is not working

```
App.controller("NewsController", '$scope') {     
     $scope.searchNewsOrGuidelines = function () {
          $scope.filterOptions.filterText = $scope.searchtext;
          $scope.NewsGridConfiguration;
     }   
     $scope.filterOptions = {
            filterText: ''
     };
     $scope.NewsGridConfiguration = {
            url: "someurl/Get",
            logoOptions: $scope.logoOptions,
            columnDefinitions: some def
            filterOptions: {            
                  filterOptions: $scope.filterOptions,
                  useExternalFilter: true
            },
            filter: $scope.searchtext
     };                   
     $scope.NewsGridOptions = {
            gridConfiguration: $scope.NewsGridConfiguration,
            filterOptions: {
                 filterOptions: $scope.filterOptions,
                useExternalFilter: true
            }
     };
}]);
```

Can somebody point out the mistake I'm doing?

Answer (score 0):

```
filterOptions: {
                 filterOptions: $scope.filterOptions,
                useExternalFilter: true
            }
```

**Instead of this, try this one, it should fix the problem:**

```
filterOptions: $scope.filterOptions
```